# Why am I able to access the module defined in main.rs without pub?

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and I am unable to understand how the module system and `pub` works.

Take the following [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e1cef40d777f11065807091cf7e3fae7):

```
fn main() {
    Test::test();
}

mod Test {
    pub fn test() {
        println!("Hello World");
    }
}
```

**Why doesn't the compiler give me an error stating that `mod Test` is `private` ?**

If I declare another module within Test and don't mark it as `pub` I get the expected error. For example:

```
fn main() {
    Test::inner::test();
}

mod Test {
    mod inner {
        pub fn test() {
            println!("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

**Are the top-level modules by default accessible in the file they are declared in ?**

What is the rule ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not just the top-level module, *every* module is accessible in the file it is declared in (or more precisely, in the *module* it is declared in).

Modules are not special in this regard: all items behave the same. Replace `mod Test {}` with `fn test() {}`. Is it clear now? The item `Test` is visible in the module it is declares inside (and any submodule of it). All items, even if private, are available to the module they're declared in.

`test()`, on the other hand, is also available to the module it is declared in - that is, `Test`. It is not available outside of it (except within submodules of it) - so it is an error to use it in the top-level module.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is: items are always accessible to their siblings and descendants (and descendants of siblings), and `pub` makes an item (and its `pub` children) visible to anyone who has access to its parent (e.g. its parent's siblings).

(Note that it doesn't matter what items these are, the same rules apply to crates, modules, functions, traits, structs and struct fields.)

---

This is the "family tree" of your example:

```
crate |- main
      |- Test +- test
```

The `Test` module is private to the crate root. So, external crates can not access it, but siblings (items in your crate) can.

The `test` function is public inside `Test`, which makes it available to anyone who has access to `Test`.

The `main` function is the sibling of `Test`, so it can access `Test` and hence `test` as well.

---

Instead of your second example, let me use another one:

```
mod Test {
    mod inner {
        pub fn test() {
            println!("Hello World");
        }
        fn can_access_test() {
            inner::test();
        }
    }
    fn can_also_access_test() {
        inner::test();
    }
}
fn cant_access_test() {
    //Test::inner::test();
}
```

```
crate |- test |- inner +- test
      |       |        |- can_access_test
      |       |- can_also_access_test
      |- cant_access_test
```

- `can_access_test` can access it because it's a sibling of it.
- `can_also_access_test` can access it because `test` is `pub`, which makes it accessible in its parent's scope, and `can_also_access_test` is a sibling of said parent.
- `cant_access_test` can access `Test` (it's a sibling of it), but it can't access `inner` (`inner` is not `pub`) and so it can't access `test` either.

---

Also, `pub use` can create "symbolic links" in the structure: it acts as if it "adopted" all `use`d items as its parent's direct children. But thinking about `pub use` *is* mind-bending, so save that for later.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [Rust Reference :: Visibility and Privacy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html)

> If an item is public, then it can be accessed externally from some module m if you can access all the item's ancestor modules from m. You can also potentially be able to name the item through re-exports. See below.
>
> If an item is private, it may be accessed by the current module and its descendants.

In the first example, `main` and `Test` belong to the same current module - the module of your source file, thus `main` has access to public items in `Test`, i.e. `test`

In the second example, `mod inner` is private